# How to test the value of a xml param

Tags: xml, ant

I'm blocked with the following problem :

I have a file web.xml which contains several infos, tags and filters.

I would like to stop processing in case of the param-name 'guard' of the filter-name 'AdministratorGuardFilter' has the param-value = 'true'

web.xml is formated like this :

```
<filter>
<filter-name>Character encoding filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>ergonomics.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
<filter-name>AdministratorGuardFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>security.common.AdministratorGuard</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>guard</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>    

<filter-mapping>     
 <filter-name>AdministratorGuardFilter</filter-name>    
 <url-pattern>/administrator/*</url-pattern>
```

Any idea ?

Many thanks in advance for help or hints

Didier.

Answer (score 1):

The following Ant script uses the third-party [`<xmltask>`](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/). `<xmltask>` can map an XML node selected by an XPath expression into an Ant property.

```
<project name="ant-xmltask-web-xml-extract" default="run" basedir=".">
    <!-- The elements of a web.xml file are in an XML namespace. To have -->
    <!-- <xmltask> ignore namespaces, we put a ':' in front of each element -->
    <!-- name. ':' tells the XPath mechanism to use the local name of the -->
    <!-- element. -->
    <property 
        name="xpath.expression"
        value="/:web-app/:filter[:filter-name/text() = 'AdministratorGuardFilter']/:init-param[:param-name/text() = 'guard']/:param-value/text()"
    />

    <target name="run">
        <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask" />
        <xmltask>
            <fileset file="web.xml"/>
            <copy path="${xpath.expression}" property="guard.value"/>
        </xmltask>

        <fail message="guard param for AdministratorGuardFilter is true.">
            <condition>
                <equals arg1="${guard.value}" arg2="true"/>
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </target>
</project>
```